# Is there a Feature Outline?

Tags: specflow

In my application,  the set of tests for an Estimate and Invoice are very similar. I can use the Scenario Outline and Examples to repeat a test with these types. But how do I repeat **all** the tests within a feature with examples and not repeat the examples at every scenario outline?

For example, is there a way I can rewrite the tests below without having the state the examples twice?

```
Scenario Outline: Adding a sales line item
    Given I have a <Transaction>
    And Add Hours of quantity 2 and rate 3
    When I save
    Then the total is 6 
Examples:
    | Transaction   |
    | Invoice       |
    | Estimate      |

Scenario Outline: Adding two sales line item
    Given I have a <Transaction>
    And Add Hours of quantity 2 and rate 3
    And Add Hours of quantity 5 and rate 2
    When I save
    Then the total is 16    
Examples:
    | Transaction   |
    | Invoice       |
    | Estimate      |
```

In other words, is there such a thing called, for a lack of a better, Feature Outline?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly Gherkin language does not support anything like this